# Conscience - when is it countable noun?

Tags: countability, countable-nouns

The dictionary says ‘conscience’ can be both countable and uncountable noun. Then when it should be written with article ‘a’?

“The best equipment ... is a conscience, common sense and health. ... Concience makes us ...”

Comment: “A flowing water isn’t frozen so easily.” In this sentence, I think that it says a specific kind of water, so that article a can be used. But the grammar book says the article shouldn’t be there. Would you explain this, please?

Answer (score 1):

Each person has a conscience; four people have four consciences. One person may have a conscience that permits him to kill small dogs for fun; another person may not.